# How to calculate PTK from PMK (WPA simulation)

Tags: hash, wpa

Im writing a WPA simulation but I cant figure out the transform for the PTK from PMK.

I calculated the PMK = PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1(passphrase,essid,strlen(essid),4096,32) using openssl library. The PTK is something like some_hash_function(PMK,anouce+snouce+bssid+clientssid,iterations) but it isnt clear in the text Im working from. I tried checking aircrack source code but it's all a little confusing.

Can anyone tell me which hash function i need and what the arguments need to be?

EDIT: Found a solution. Hope this helps someone, code dump follows:

```
    /* Calculate PMK */
    pmk = (unsigned char *) error_checked_malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * PMK_SIZE);
    if(PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1(passphrase, strlen(passphrase)-1, essid, 
                                            strlen(essid), PMK_ITERATION, PMK_SIZE, pmk) != 0) /* ignore LF or NULL with strlen(passphrase)-1 */
                    {
    if(SHOWPMK || verbosity >= 2)
            printf("\nPMK(#%04d)", num);
    else
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1 failed on PMK\n", PROG_NAME);

    /* Calculate PTK */
    /* PTK = PRF-X(PMK, "Pairwise key expansion", Min(AA, SA) || Max(AA, SA) || Min(ANonce, SNonce) || Max(ANonce, SNonce)) */

    HMAC(EVP_sha1(), name, 4, somestring, 36, ptk, NULL);
    // PTK[0:16] = KCK
    **************************/

    ptk = (unsigned char *) error_checked_malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * PTK_SIZE);
    if(HMAC(EVP_sha1(), pmk, PMK_SIZE, pke, PKE_SIZE, ptk, NULL) != 0)
    {
            if(SHOWPTK || verbosity >= 2)
                    printf("\nPTK(#%04d)", num);
            else
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s: HMAC_SHA1 failed on PTK\n", PROG_NAME);

    /* Calculate MIC | PRF-384 CCMP or PRF-512 TKIP */
    if(TKIPFLAG)
            HMAC(EVP_md5(), ptk, PTK_SIZE-4, eapol, eapolsize, kckmic, NULL);
    else
            HMAC(EVP_sha1(), ptk, PTK_SIZE-4, eapol, eapolsize, kckmic, NULL);
```

Comment: Two questions: 1) Can you show us, how you try to compute PMK with openssl? 2) What is the reference of the text you are working with?

Comment: This was about 2 years ago. I figured it out in the end. Thanks! :)

Comment: OK, no problem but if you have already a solution can you 1) post the solution or 2) delete the question ?